# sqlite3 foreign keys on PDO

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I use PDO for connecting to sqlite3, but I cannot make foreign keys working for some reason. According to docs, this "PRAGMA short_column_names=1" should enable that. I do this:

```
$con = new PDO('sqlite:z:/testing.db');
$res = $con->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON');
var_dump($res);die();
```

Which returns me 0. I tried creating actual tables with foreign keys and it did not work.
Direct requests to SQLite3 class worked though:

```
$con = new SQLite3('z:/testing.db');
$con->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;');
var_dump($con->query('PRAGMA foreign_keys;')->fetchArray());
```

This reutrns array(2) { [0]=> int(1) ["foreign_keys"]=> int(1) }

According to SQLite3::version(), I have sqlite version 3.7.7.1. My PHP version is 5.3.18, running on Windows.

Please help me get it running with PDO. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not aware of the idea that `PRAGMA short_column_names=1;` should be issued with PDO in order for foreign key constraints to work with SQLite. You *should* however issue `PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;` with PDO as well.

Give this a try:

```
<?php

// SQL for creating database structure
$databaseSql = <<<SQL
    CREATE TABLE `user` (
        `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        `name` TEXT NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE( `name` )
    );

    CREATE TABLE `userProfile` (
        `userId` INTEGER NOT NULL CONSTRAINT `userProfile_userId` REFERENCES `user`( `id` ) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
        `image` TEXT NOT NULL
    );
SQL;

// SQL for inserting dummy data
$dataSql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO `user` VALUES( 1, "John" );
    INSERT INTO `user` VALUES( 2, "Mary" );
    INSERT INTO `user` VALUES( 3, "Joe" );
    INSERT INTO `userProfile` VALUES( 1, "/images/john.jpg" );
    INSERT INTO `userProfile` VALUES( 2, "/images/mary.jpg" );
    INSERT INTO `userProfile` VALUES( 3, "/images/joe.jpg" );
SQL;

// create a temporary SQLite instance in memory
$db = new PDO( 'sqlite::memory:', null, null, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
) );

// activate use of foreign key constraints
$db->exec( 'PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;' );

// create database
$db->exec( $databaseSql );
// insert dummy data
$db->exec( $dataSql );

// should dump 3 records
var_dump( $db->query( 'SELECT * FROM `userProfile`;' )->fetchAll() );

// delete 1 user, cascade deleting 1 userProfile as well
$db->exec( 'DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `id` = 1;' );

// should dump 2 records
var_dump( $db->query( 'SELECT * FROM `userProfile`;' )->fetchAll() );
```

It should result in the following:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["image"]=>
    string(16) "/images/john.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["image"]=>
    string(16) "/images/mary.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["image"]=>
    string(15) "/images/joe.jpg"
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["image"]=>
    string(16) "/images/mary.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["userId"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["image"]=>
    string(15) "/images/joe.jpg"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the detailed example! You're right, I used PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON. Just wrote it wrong on the question. Your example works just fine, I will dig deeper, probably there's another issue with my app. $con->exec('PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON') will always return 0 for PDO even on success, that was my confusion.

Comment: @PavelDubinin The fact that `PDO::exec()` returns `0` is [because it will return the number of rows affected](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php#refsect1-pdo.exec-returnvalues). And `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON` doesn't affect any rows. If the statement produced an error, it would have returned `false`.

Comment: @PavelDubinin Yes, you already have that in your own example. ;-) `$con->query('PRAGMA foreign_keys;')->fetchColumn(0));` (but I use [`fetchColumn(0)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) here) which should return `1` if foreign keys are enabled, `0` if not.

Comment: that was when using SQLite3 directly, but I want to check that using PDO.

Comment: The SQL statements you issue generally don't differ per library. The libraries (PDO, SQLite3, etc.) are merely different 'gateways' to the same database (sqlite3).

Comment: Ok, I think you may be misunderstanding something important: be aware that you need to enable foreign keys every time again when you connect to your database. Even if the database already exists. Otherwise Sqlite simply ignores the foreign keys you have defined in your database. In other words, issue `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` every time you connect to your database, before you issue other SQL statements to the database.

Comment: yes, I know that. It acutally works, sorry.. it was a long working week :) Thanks alot for you help, you saved me alot of time.